# Delete all occurrences of an item in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

This code takes an item as an argument and deletes all occurrences of the item in the linked list. It works well with my testing. Is there anything that I am missing? Can this code be improved further?

```
void
LinkedList::DeleteAllOccurences(int key) {
   Node *temp = head;
   Node *prev = head;
   while(temp!=NULL) {
      if(temp->item == key){
         if(temp == head) {
            head = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = head;
         } else {
            prev->next = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = prev->next;
         }
      } else {
         prev = temp;
         temp = temp->next;
      }
   }
   return;
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing context.  What does `Node` look like, what members does the `LinkedList` class have?  How are `Node`s created?  Your previous question suggests that `LinkedList` has a `tail` member, which you're not addressing in the posted code. Without the context, we're left guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code can be improved by not handling the head as a special case. Yes, that means using a double-pointer, but the structure gets much more straight-forward and shorter:

```
void LinkedList::DeleteAllOccurences(int key) {
    Node** p = &head;
    while(*p)
        if((*p)->item == key) {
            Node* tmp = (*p)->next;
            delete *p;
            *p = tmp;
        } else
            p = &(*p)->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to double pointers is using a dummy node that initially points to head, and after you are done with removing the items you restore the head in case its node got deleted:

```
void
LinkedList::DeleteAllOccurences(int key) {
   Node dummy;
   dummy.next = head;
   Node *node = &dummy;
   while (node->next != NULL) {
      if (node->next->item == key) {
         Node *temp = node->next;
         node->next = temp->next;
         delete temp;
      } else {
         node = node->next;
      }
   }
   head = dummy.next;
   return;
}
```